# Order yaml's map based on user defined sequence in file using yq

Tags: bash, yaml, yq

I've have a document containing maps, e.g.

```yaml
aaa: hello
bbb: world
ccc: foo
ddd: bar
```

I've `./order.yaml` containing

```yaml
- ccc
- aaa
- bbb
- eee
```

I'm trying to reorder the first document based on the order defined in the file. This should be done with something like (see [this](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/1199))

```bash
document='aaa: hello
bbb: world
ccc: foo
ddd: bar'
yq '. |= pick(load("order.yaml"))'<<<"$document"
```

but I get `{}` as output.

Notice that this works if I do

```bash
document='aaa: hello
bbb: world
ccc: foo
ddd: bar'
yq '. |= pick(["ccc", "aaa", "bbb", "eee"])'<<<"$document"
```

giving

```yaml
ccc: foo
aaa: hello
bbb: world
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

My yq knowledge is limited but one fix seems to be:

```
yq '. |= pick( []+load("order.yaml") )'<<<"$document"
```

or just:

```
yq 'pick( []+load("order.yaml") )'<<<"$document"
```

---

Hint taken from https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/load :

> Note that you can use string operators like `+` and `sub` to modify the value in the yaml file to a path that exists in your system.

Comment: This works, thanks. I do not understand why that `[]` is needed though. I interpreted the sentence you are mentioning in the sense of string concatenation (`load("../../examples/" + "file.yaml")`) or in the other senses given in the examples.

Comment: I have no idea either. I've asked on gihub - https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/discussions/1805 - will update here if I get an answer